# Is there a way to tie up even and "newly suggested odd" Riemann zeta values?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory

Define the sequence
$$a_s=(-1)^{\binom{s-1}2}\left(\frac{\pi}2\right)^s\frac1{2\cdot s!}\begin{cases} s\,E_{s-1}, \qquad \text{if $s$ is odd} \\ 2^{2s}B_s, \qquad \,\,\text{if $s$ is even};\end{cases}$$
where $E_s$ and $B_s$ are Euler and Bernoulli numbers, respectively.

Of course, we know that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^{2s}}=a_{2s} \qquad \text{and} \qquad
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)^{2s-1}}=a_{2s-1}.$$
The focus here is that each $a_s$ is rational multiple of a power of $\pi$ unlike the classical Riemann zeta function at odd values of $s$. A few examples are in order: for $s\geq1$,
$$\frac{\pi}4, \frac{\pi^2}6, \frac{\pi^3}{32}, \frac{\pi^4}{90}, \frac{5\pi^5}{1536}, \frac{\pi^6}{945}, \frac{61\pi^7}{184320}, \frac{\pi^8}{9450}, \,\,\dots$$
Now, I like to ask:

> **QUESTION.** Is there a function $F(s)$, continuous in real $s$, whose values are $F(s)=a_s$ at integral $s$? One may try upgrading this to a meromorphic function.

Comment: Nice idea of course to accommodate those powers of $\pi$. But as the ratios of consecutive values form a zigzag pattern,  I'd guess that $F''(x)$ would already have zeros between each pair of consecutive naturals... so I don't think there will be a very satisfying function to interpolate.

Comment: For any sequence $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ one can find an entire function $f$ such that $f(n) = b_n$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1529860/304290 . To get an interesting answer you probably need more conditions on $F$.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more "natural" to define $a_{2s}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^{2s-1}}$, that is rescaling it by $1-1/2^{2s}$? Or even better, what about $a_s=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{\pi i s(n-1)}}{(2n-1)^s}$?

Answer (score 3):

The function
$$f(s):=\sin(\tfrac{\pi}{2}(s+1)) \zeta(s)+\sin(\tfrac{\pi s}{2}) L(\tfrac{s+1}{2})\tag{1}$$
where $L(s)$ is the second Dirichlet series
$$L(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2 n-1)^{2 s-1}}\tag{2}$$
which is valid for $\Re(s)>1$ but which can be analytically extended using the [Hurwitz zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function) as
$$L(s)=\frac{\zeta \left(2 s-1,\frac{1}{4}\right)-\zeta \left(2 s-1,\frac{3}{4}\right)}{4^{2 s-1}}\tag{3}$$
gives the two sequences except for this sign
$$\underset{s\to 1}{\text{lim}}f(s)=-\frac{\pi }{4}, f(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}, f(3)=-\frac{\pi^3}{32}, f(4)=\frac{\pi^4}{90},\dots\tag{4}$$
and you can square the trigonometric functions to get the sign.

The plot of the function in Mathematica for 2<s<30 is a nice sine like wave, but this is all trivial.

Figure (1) below illustrates formula (1) for $f(s)$ in blue using formula (3) for $L(s)$ where the red discrete evaluation points illustrate the evaluation of formula (1) at integer values of $s$.

---

[image: Illustration of Formula (1) for f(s)]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of Formula (1) for $f(s)$

---

Squaring the $sin$ terms in formula (1) for $f(s)$ above leads to $g(s)$ defined below which evaluates correctly in sign as well as magnitude.

$$g(s)=\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(s+1)\right)\ \zeta(s)+\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\ L\left(\frac{s+1}{2}\right)\tag{5}$$

Figure (2) below illustrates formula (5) for $g(s)$ in blue using formula (3) for $L(s)$ where the red discrete evaluation points illustrate the evaluation of $a_s$ defined in the question above at integer values of $s$.

---

[image: Illustration of Formula (5) for g(s)]

**Figure (2)**: Illustration of Formula (5) for $g(s)$ (blue curve) and $a_s$ (red evaluation points)

---

Comment: I'm having problems verifying your result. By "where $L(s)$ is the second Dirichlet series", do you mean $L_{2,1}(s)=\left(1-2^{-s}\right) \zeta (s)$?

Comment: @Clark my $L(s)$ is defined as $$L(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)^{2s-1}}.$$

Comment: @juan: do you mind posting the Mathematica plot?

Comment: @Amdeberham I am not sure I know how to do that. L[s_] := Sum[(-1)^(n - 1)/(2 n - 1)^(2 s - 1), {n, 1, Infinity}]; f[s_] := Sin[(Pi (s + 1))/2] Zeta[s] + Sin[(Pi (s))/2] L[(s + 1)/2]; Table[f[s], {s, 2, 8}]

Comment: @Amdeberham it was interesting the Plot of the complex function $t \mapsto e^{-\pi t/2} \zeta(1/2+it).  The zeros of this function are not on the critical line. (in general).

Comment: @Amdeberham  When $s >5$ say,  $\zeta(s)$ and $L(s)$ are practically 1. So the plot is indistinguishable from that of $$\sin(\pi(s+1)/2)+\sin(\pi s/2)=\sqrt{2}\sin(\pi s/2+ \pi/4)$$